Ktor - finished with non-zero exit value 134
Hello fellow engineers!
I'm currently having a problem with my ktor project. You'll find a longer description of the problem in the following link.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-7060/Ktor-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-134
If you want to try it out just clone the mentioned github repository and execute runDebugExecutableLinuxX64.
Any help is highly appreciated!
Thank you all in advance!

What's unclear about the error message Neither port nor sslPort specified?

So when looking into the github repository you see that the port is defined. As you can see here the sslPort is not required. https://ktor.io/docs/server-configuration-file.html#config-basic

Are you sure the resources of commonMain are used? https://stackoverflow.com/q/60033320/2308683

Questions here need to be self-contained, with all relevant details here in the question, as a [mcve]. Links can break, and linked content can change (especially on github!), making the question useless for others with similar problems. See [ask]. Also, what do you expect us to do if there's already a bug report with the maintainer?

Yes, sorry. I found a solution. It was the Missing resourcesDir. Sorry dorgot to Close this issue
